# Implementation of Tableau LOD in Qlikview

Tags: tableau-api, qlikview

In tableau, the expressions are

```
{Include Provider_data,Provider_Key,Provider_Item,Provider_service,Class_key,Schedule_price_key,Conftype_key:Max(Effective_Date)}
```

And other is

```
{Fixed Provider_data,Provider_Key,Provider_Item,Provider_service,Class_key,Schedule_price_key,Conftype_key:Max(Effective_Date)}.
```

How can we achieve these expressions in Qlikview ?

Answer (score 0):

The most similar approach could be the TOTAL keyword, inside a Max (or other aggregation function).

```
Max(TOTAL <Provider_Key> Effective_Date)
```

The previous code will ignore the Provider_Key dimension, even if you are working in a lower level of detail. Hope this will guide you.

Comment: There are two expressions one for INCLUDE function and other for FIXED function. So this answer is for which expressions and what is the solution for other one??

Comment: The solution will work inside an expression (in a chart). Are you looking for a solution for the QlikView load script?